# using LINQ from Database to List in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

i have a t_my_class table structure like below (MySql table)

```
id     class     group     age     name     surname
1      9         A         18      sarah    brown
2      10        B         20      joe      sanders
3      8         A         17      elisa    connor
4      10        C         23      sandra   brown
```

and i have a struct and a list of that struct

```
struct MyClass
{
   int id;
   string class;
   string group;
   int age;
   string name;
   string surname;
}
List<MyClass> Students = new List<MyClass>();
```

Now, can u tell me which LINQ query to use to select all data from t_my_class table to Students List.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, that should almost certainly not be a `struct` - it should be a `class`. Now, you have a couple of choices; if you *do* already have a LINQ-enabled ORM hooked up, then it should be simply:

```
var students = myContext.Students.ToList();
```

If you *aren't* already using an ORM tool then a micro-ORM might help, for example dapper-dot-net works with MySql AFAIK, allowing:

```
var students = connection.Query<Student>("select * from t_my_class").ToList();
```

With:

```
class Student
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Class {get;set;}
   public string Group {get;set;}
   public int Age {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string Surname {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why we shouldnt use a Struct? (purely interested).

Comment: @christofr structs are very rare, and unless you know *exactly* why you are using a struct, a class should be assumed. In particular, structs make poor choices for "object"-type data (and a student is an object, rather than a value). Specific reasons: it is over-sized for a struct, would *probably* be incorrectly mutable, and the copy-semantics usually cause huge headaches.

Answer (score 1):

```
var students = from std in Students
               select std.
```

[image]

More : [Learn SQL to LINQ (Visual Representation)](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2010/12/sql-to-linq-visual-representation.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
var students = from p in entities.t_my_class 
select p;
```